Laser install on Ender 3. New 24 V Board with 12 V laser output
I just wanted to reach out quick here. I bought a CNC board with 24 V input and a 3 pin 12 V output but I've seen many people saying a buck converter is needed. The board I have specifically says on it "12 V laser".
I have tried two other control boards each rated from 7 V to 24 V  with a PWM output (I never connected the laser out of fear of the output being incorrect). But even just connecting power, the steppers, limiters, and USB one of the voltage regulators got extremely hot on both of them. To the point it burned me. I'm assuming they were shorted. I only used a 12 V 6 A PSU so I'm confused as to how this would have shorted the regulator if only half the rated voltage was being input.
The parts I have right now are the Mecpow X3 10 W laser module I got from a friend, CNCTOPBAOS 3 Axis GRBL 1.1f USB Port (this board), this PSU 12 V 6 A Power Supply Adapter - AC Adapter 100-240 V 50 60 Hz DC 12 Volt 6 A 72 W Power Converter Transformer, and the steppers/limiters from the Ender 3.
The last attempt did have LightBurn recognize the board briefly and I got a single command to it but then it wouldn't recognize it any more and the voltage regulator was hot.
Any assistance or tips would be greatly appreciated.
